# what happens to leading zeroes during type coercion in array indexes?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, type-coercion

say for an example,

```
let years = [1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010];
console.log(years['2'] === years['02']); // is false
```

and

```
console.log(years[2] === years[02]); // is true
```

like i referred "2 is coerced into a string by the JavaScript engine through an implicit toString conversion" is there an inbuilt method to suppress the leading zeros in JavaScript engine, or else is it  happening in the browser?

Comment: `console.log(years[Number('2')] === years[Number('02')]); // is true`?

Comment: yes it is true!

Comment: you could also write `years["02" * 1]` it will also be true. just multiply your string by 1

Comment: yeah perfect, it became true!

Comment: @Ifaruki So it means that the inbuilt Number() is taking care of those leading zeroes? am i correct?

Comment: yea for strings. but watch out: if you type in `Number(011)` you get 9 instead of 11 but `Number("011")` is 11. i would go simply with multiply by 1